# Spinner в Material Design стиле

Tags: android, android-spinner

Возможно ли сделать Spinner (выпадающий список) в стиле Mataterial Design? Можете подсказать ссылку на хорошую библиотеку или же на тутор?

Answer (score 3):

Простейший и лучший вариант - используйте одну из тем из библиотеки поддержки AppCompat, все ее виджеты в стиле Material Design, при этом вы используете стандартные классы Android.

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
  ...
</style>
```

Так же на Github есть множество библиотек, которые были актуальны до выхода официальной библиотеки поддержки от Google - [например](https://github.com/rey5137/material)